# How do you archive Runner.app created with Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, deployment, build, archive

I created my first Flutter app and I am trying to deploy it to the App Store following the [official steps described here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios).
I successfully added team: 
[screenshot of my apple developer team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfrFq.png)
I have an error on creating an archive with the command Product => Archive:

Signing for "Runner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

I tried to archive with a different app, doesn't help.

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-TM)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/amanokerim/Dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (8 days ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/amanokerim/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.1, Build version 12A7403
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.17.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup the team setting in `Release` configuration.

[image]